# Annotating Transactions

Tags: transactions, mist, wallets, jaxx

Is there an Ethereum wallet which provides the ability to annotate transactions like Electrum does for Bitcoin? It would be really useful. I can't find a way to do it in Mist. Thanks for any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this if you login to etherscan.io now. Very bottom of the transaction page. As simple as it gets.

Comment: You mean download a CSV? That's not what I'm looking for. I want notes to be integrated into my wallet.